# Regular Expressions: replace extra slashes/backslashes from a path

Tags: c#, regex, path, absolute-path

I have a string which I would like to remove extra slashes following below criteria:

- If extra slashes are at the beginning of the string I want to remove them if there are more than 4 in a row. I want to replace them by 4 slashes.
- If extra slashes are not at the beginning but in other places of the string, I want to remove them and replace them by 2 slashes if there are more than 2 in a row.

So I have tried below without success:

```
string myPath = "/////this///is//an////absolute//path";
        

// below check if there are more than 4 slashes at the beginning. If so replace them by 4 slashes
string url  = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(myPath  , @"^(/+){4}", @"////");
// below check if there are extra slashes (more than 2) in other parts of string (excluding the beginning of the string). If so, replace them by 2 slashes.
url= System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(url, @"(/+){3}", @"//");
```

Example:

```
string = "/////this///is//an////absolute//path"
```

**Expected url**:

```
////this//is//and//absolute//path
```

**Current url**:

```
//this//is//and//absolute//path
```

Also I would like to do it in a single regex instead of split it in two statements and working in case of backslashes instead of slashes, for example, the same regular expression should be able to do it as well:

```
\\\\\this\\\is\\an\\\\absolute\\path
```

**Expected**:

```
\\\\this\\is\\an\\absolute\\path
```

Also It should be valid for below paths (with all slashes or backslashes):

```
c:\\\\\this\\\is\\an\\\\absolute\\path
```

**Expected**:

```
c:\\this\\is\\an\\absolute\\path
```

So there are cases where string comes with all slashes or all backslashes and I need it to work for both cases.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if slashes/backslashes are just at the beginning I need it to be 4 slashes/backslashes and in the rest of the string always replaced by two slashes/backslashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest

```cs
Regex.Replace(text, @"^(([/\\])\2{3})\2+|([/\\])\3*", "$1$3$3")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rUOOfr/4). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(([/\\])\2{3})` - Group 1 capturing a `/` or `\` captured into Group 2 and then matching the char captured into Group 2 three times
- `\2+` - one or more occurrences of Group 2 value
- `|` - or
- `([/\\])\3*` - Group 3 capturing a `/` or `\` and then matching zero or more (back)slashes.

Comment: Your solution works great! I forgot to indicate in the post that I need to always put 4 slashes/backslashes at the beginning if there are extra ones (more than 4) and also less than 4. If there are just 4 slashes/backslashes at the beginning no need to to nothing at the beginning, just leave beginning as is.  How could i modify your regex to do it? Anyway vote for you!

Comment: @Ralph Although this is all possible with a match evaluator in `Regex.Replace` method, I think it would be easier with something like `var result = $@"\\\\{Regex.Replace(text, @"^([/\\])\1*|([/\\])\2*", "$2$2")}";`.

Comment: Hey, I checked your regex in an online C# compiler and it was working well. Now I have implemented it in my real C# app and it is not working, it seems like expression System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(path, @"^([/\\])\1*|([/\\])\2*", "$2$2") returns "this\\\\is\\\\an\\\\absolute\\\\path" where I pass in path="\\\\\\this\\is\\an\\absolute\\path". Instead it should return "this\\is\\an\\absolute\\path"

Comment: @Ralph See [the C# demo](https://ideone.com/WrDnOG), looks fine.

Comment: Yes, I have seen, and the output through Console.WriteLine is done correctly but if you put a breakpoint and see what is the value that result variable is storing, then will see it stores "\\\\\\\\this\\\\is\\\\an\\\\absolute\\\\path". Console.WriteLine understands that backslashes are escaped so it outputs: \\\\this\\is\\an\\absolute\\path

Comment: @Ralph The console stores nothing, it displays the string literal view. It is not the real text.

Comment: so I need varaible result to store the same as console.writeline outputs, that is: \\\\this\\is\\an\\absolute\\path

Comment: @Ralph Then use `Regex.Replace(path, @"^(([/\\])\2{3})\2+|([/\\])\3*", "$2$2$3")`. Or, `var result = $@"\\{Regex.Replace(path, @"^([/\\])\1*|([/\\])\2*", "$2")}"`, see [this C# demo](https://ideone.com/pS4bmd).